# Navbar doesn't cover the full width of the page on certain phones

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navbar

I'm currently making my website responsive and making sure it looks good on mobile/tablets. While doing this I discovered that my fixed navigation bar, with a width set to 100vw, don't cover the width of the page if I pinch-zoom out (a friend also informed me that the navbar didn't cover the width of his phone screen even before he zoomed out).

Before I zoom out:
[image]

After zooming out
[image]

I've tried finding a solution online but came up empty handed. I also tried changing my navbar from 100vw to 100% but the problem still stands. How could I go about fixing this?

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question doesn't meet our standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your width of the navbar is set at 100vw, which means 100% of the viewport is covered which is exactly your case because the navbar covers the whole screen before pinching it out.
Try setting your navbar width to 100% instead of 100vw.

Also, there is an issue with your image sizing which is why you are actually able to pinch out in the first place.

So correct your image dimensions or change your navbar width to 100%. Both should work.

Correcting the image dimensions is preferable.

If you are using something like Bootstrap, you don't need to add the width in the first place.

Please share the code if further clarification is needed.

Comment: All your information should be in your answer, not down here in comments.

Comment: Changing the width of the image div with @media screen removed the horizontal scroll bar thus solving my issue. Thank you